# SweerAlert2 - How to change responsive image in alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design, screen-resolution

I have this SweetAlert2 JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

swal.fire({ position: 'center', customClass: 'swal-height', showConfirmButton: false, 
width: 600, padding: 150, background: '#fff url(../custom/media/misc/IMAGE1.jpg) 
no-repeat', backdrop: 'rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.65)', timer: 10000 }); 

});
```

This script works fine in desktop screens - but as IMAGE1 has 600x600 pixels - it will be big for mobile devices.

Then I need to change the image to IMAGE2 (with a small width) to make it works at small devices.

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

best solution that I found:

split the screen resolution via JavaScript and add a CSS control for small-devices

```
$(document).ready(function(){

if (screen.width > 800) {
swal.fire({ position: 'center', customClass: 'swal-height', showConfirmButton: false, 
width: 600, padding: 150, background: '#fff url(../custom/media/misc/IMAGE2.jpg) 
no-repeat', backdrop: 'rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.65)', timer: 10000 }); 
}
if (screen.width >= 800) {
swal.fire({ position: 'center', customClass: 'swal-height', showConfirmButton: false, 
width: 600, padding: 150, background: '#fff url(../custom/media/misc/IMAGE1.jpg) 
no-repeat', backdrop: 'rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.65)', timer: 10000 }); 
}
});
```

and CSS:(sweetalert2 demands the height control via css)

```
.swal-height {
    height: 600px;
    width: 600px;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .swal-height {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked about the best practice, the answer is to use **srcset**, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images#Resolution_switching_Different_sizes

Comment: tks @nowres-rafed! help me a lot! :D

Answer (score 0):

you don't need two seperate images, you can just add `max-width:100%` to the image element. Then it will not exceed 100% of screen width, whatever it's set `width` is.

Comment: Hi @gindev, first of all, tks for your precious time to help me. I will try this and came back soon with feedback. :D

Answer (score 0):

I used the media attributes and found the class name via the developer console:

```
@media (max-width: 915px) {
.swal2-modal {
  margin-left: -170px;
  width: 70%;
  height: 70%;
}
 }
}
```

Adjust the size as needed.